# How to solve an equation for a variable in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, differential-equations, algebra

I want to solve this equation in MATLAB. I know via numerical solver that some of the roots are imaginary and others real. Using solve, MATLAB spits out a list of conditions under which the solution is valid.

I just want MATLAB to solve this with an analytical solution (not numerically, I can do this in Mathematica). Is there a better solution, or any other package that I can use?

```
syms f2 ep1 ep2 a1 a2 fp1 fp2 h e1 m1 mp R f r t1 f1

eqn = (((ep2*fp1 - ep1*fp2)*mp*(e1*m1*(ep2*f2*fp1*(fp2 - a2*mp) +...
ep1*fp2*(-(f1*fp2) + a2*f2*mp))*(h + R) + a2*f2*(-(ep2*f*f2*fp1*R)+...
ep1*f*f1*fp2*R - ...
ep1*ep2*(f1 - f2)*mp*r*(h + R)))* (a1*ep1*ep2*f1*(f1 - f2)...
*mp*(ep2*f*f2*fp1*R - ep1*f*f1*fp2*R + ep1*ep2*(f1 - f2)*mp*r*(h + R)) +... 
e1*(ep2^2*f*f2^2*fp1^2*R*t1 + ...
ep1^2*f1*fp2*(f*f1*fp2*R*t1 - ep2*(f1 - f2)*mp*(h + R)*(-(fp1*m1) + ... 
a1*m1*mp + r*t1)) + ...
ep1*ep2*fp1*(-2*f*f1*f2*fp2*R*t1 + ep2*(f1 - f2)*mp*(h + R)*(-(f2*fp1*m1)+... 
a1*f1*m1*mp + f2*r*t1)))))/...
(e1*ep1*ep2*(ep2*f2*fp1 - ep1*f1*fp2)^2*(h + R)^2*(ep1*ep2*(f1 - f2)*...
(-(a2*f2*fp1) + a1*f1*fp2)*mp + e1*(ep2*f2*fp1*(fp2 - a2*mp) + ...
ep1*fp2*(-(f1*fp2) + a2*f2*mp))*t1))) * (-1) == 0;

solve(eqn,fp1)


The solutions I get are:
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  (a2*f2*(R*ep1*f*f1*fp2 - ep1*ep2*mp*r*(R + h)*(f1 - f2)) - e1*ep1*fp2*m1*(R + h)*(f1*fp2 - a2*f2*mp))/(R*a2*ep2*f*f2^2 - e1*ep2*m1*(R + h)*(fp2 - a2*mp)*f2)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   (ep1*fp2)/ep2
 (ep1*f1*mp*(R^2*a1^2*e1^2*ep2^2*f1^2*m1^2*mp^2 + 2*R^2*a1^2*e1*ep2^2*f*f1^2*f2*m1*mp + R^2*a1^2*ep2^2*f^2*f1^2*f2^2 + 2*R^2*a1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1^2*fp2*m1^2*mp - 4*R^2*a1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*m1^2*mp + 2*R^2*a1*e1^2*ep2^2*f1*f2*m1*mp*r*t1 - 4*R^2*a1*e1^2*ep2*f*f1*f2*fp2*m1*t1 + 4*R^2*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1^2*f2*m1*mp*r - 4*R^2*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1*f2^2*m1*mp*r - 2*R^2*a1*e1*ep1*ep2*f*f1^2*f2*fp2*m1 - 2*R^2*a1*e1*ep2^2*f*f1*f2^2*r*t1 + R^2*e1^2*ep1^2*f1^2*fp2^2*m1^2 - 2*R^2*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*m1*r*t1 + R^2*e1^2*ep2^2*f2^2*r^2*t1^2 + 2*R*a1^2*e1^2*ep2^2*f1^2*h*m1^2*mp^2 + 2*R*a1^2*e1*ep2^2*f*f1^2*f2*h*m1*mp + 4*R*a1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1^2*fp2*h*m1^2*mp - 8*R*a1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*h*m1^2*mp + 4*R*a1*e1^2*ep2^2*f1*f2*h*m1*mp*r*t1 - 4*R*a1*e1^2*ep2*f*f1*f2*fp2*h*m1*t1 + 8*R*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1^2*f2*h*m1*mp*r - 8*R*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1*f2^2*h*m1*mp*r - 2*R*a1*e1*ep1*ep2*f*f1^2*f2*fp2*h*m1 - 2*R*a1*e1*ep2^2*f*f1*f2^2*h*r*t1 + 2*R*e1^2*ep1^2*f1^2*fp2^2*h*m1^2 - 4*R*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*h*m1*r*t1 +\\\r\n 2*R*e1^2*ep2^2*f2^2*h*r^2*t1^2 + a1^2*e1^2*ep2^2*f1^2*h^2*m1^2*mp^2 + 2*a1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1^2*fp2*h^2*m1^2*mp - 4*a1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*h^2*m1^2*mp + 2*a1*e1^2*ep2^2*f1*f2*h^2*m1*mp*r*t1 + 4*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1^2*f2*h^2*m1*mp*r - 4*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1*f2^2*h^2*m1*mp*r + e1^2*ep1^2*f1^2*fp2^2*h^2*m1^2 - 2*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*h^2*m1*r*t1 + e1^2*ep2^2*f2^2*h^2*r^2*t1^2)^(1/2) - ep1*f2*mp*(R^2*a1^2*e1^2*ep2^2*f1^2*m1^2*mp^2 + 2*R^2*a1^2*e1*ep2^2*f*f1^2*f2*m1*mp + R^2*a1^2*ep2^2*f^2*f1^2*f2^2 + 2*R^2*a1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1^2*fp2*m1^2*mp - 4*R^2*a1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*m1^2*mp + 2*R^2*a1*e1^2*ep2^2*f1*f2*m1*mp*r*t1 - 4*R^2*a1*e1^2*ep2*f*f1*f2*fp2*m1*t1 + 4*R^2*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1^2*f2*m1*mp*r - 4*R^2*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1*f2^2*m1*mp*r - 2*R^2*a1*e1*ep1*ep2*f*f1^2*f2*fp2*m1 - 2*R^2*a1*e1*ep2^2*f*f1*f2^2*r*t1 + R^2*e1^2*ep1^2*f1^2*fp2^2*m1^2 - 2*R^2*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*m1*r*t1 + R^2*e1^2*ep2^2*f2^2*r^2*t1^2 + 2*R*a1^2*e1^2*ep2^2*f1^2*h*m1^2*mp^2 + 2*R*a1^2*e1*ep2^2*f*f1^2*f2*h*m1*mp + 4*R*a\\\r\n1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1^2*fp2*h*m1^2*mp - 8*R*a1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*h*m1^2*mp + 4*R*a1*e1^2*ep2^2*f1*f2*h*m1*mp*r*t1 - 4*R*a1*e1^2*ep2*f*f1*f2*fp2*h*m1*t1 + 8*R*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1^2*f2*h*m1*mp*r - 8*R*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1*f2^2*h*m1*mp*r - 2*R*a1*e1*ep1*ep2*f*f1^2*f2*fp2*h*m1 - 2*R*a1*e1*ep2^2*f*f1*f2^2*h*r*t1 + 2*R*e1^2*ep1^2*f1^2*fp2^2*h*m1^2 - 4*R*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*h*m1*r*t1 + 2*R*e1^2*ep2^2*f2^2*h*r^2*t1^2 + a1^2*e1^2*ep2^2*f1^2*h^2*m1^2*mp^2 + 2*a1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1^2*fp2*h^2*m1^2*mp - 4*a1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*h^2*m1^2*mp + 2*a1*e1^2*ep2^2*f1*f2*h^2*m1*mp*r*t1 + 4*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1^2*f2*h^2*m1*mp*r - 4*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1*f2^2*h^2*m1*mp*r + e1^2*ep1^2*f1^2*fp2^2*h^2*m1^2 - 2*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*h^2*m1*r*t1 + e1^2*ep2^2*f2^2*h^2*r^2*t1^2)^(1/2) - R*e1*ep1^2*f1^2*fp2*m1*mp - e1*ep1^2*f1^2*fp2*h*m1*mp + e1*ep1*ep2*f2^2*h*mp*r*t1 - R*a1*e1*ep1*ep2*f1^2*m1*mp^2 - a1*e1*ep1*ep2*f1^2*h*m1*mp^2 + 2*R*e1*ep1*f*f1*f2*fp2*t1 + R*a1*ep1*ep2*f*f1*f2^2*mp - R*a1*ep1*ep2*f*f1^2*f2*mp + R*e1\\\r\n*ep1^2*f1*f2*fp2*m1*mp + R*e1*ep1*ep2*f2^2*mp*r*t1 + e1*ep1^2*f1*f2*fp2*h*m1*mp - R*e1*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*mp*r*t1 - e1*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*h*mp*r*t1 + R*a1*e1*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*m1*mp^2 + a1*e1*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*h*m1*mp^2)/(2*e1*ep2*f2*(R*f*f2*t1 - R*ep1*f1*m1*mp + R*ep1*f2*m1*mp - ep1*f1*h*m1*mp + ep1*f2*h*m1*mp))
 (ep1*f2*mp*(R^2*a1^2*e1^2*ep2^2*f1^2*m1^2*mp^2 + 2*R^2*a1^2*e1*ep2^2*f*f1^2*f2*m1*mp + R^2*a1^2*ep2^2*f^2*f1^2*f2^2 + 2*R^2*a1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1^2*fp2*m1^2*mp - 4*R^2*a1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*m1^2*mp + 2*R^2*a1*e1^2*ep2^2*f1*f2*m1*mp*r*t1 - 4*R^2*a1*e1^2*ep2*f*f1*f2*fp2*m1*t1 + 4*R^2*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1^2*f2*m1*mp*r - 4*R^2*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1*f2^2*m1*mp*r - 2*R^2*a1*e1*ep1*ep2*f*f1^2*f2*fp2*m1 - 2*R^2*a1*e1*ep2^2*f*f1*f2^2*r*t1 + R^2*e1^2*ep1^2*f1^2*fp2^2*m1^2 - 2*R^2*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*m1*r*t1 + R^2*e1^2*ep2^2*f2^2*r^2*t1^2 + 2*R*a1^2*e1^2*ep2^2*f1^2*h*m1^2*mp^2 + 2*R*a1^2*e1*ep2^2*f*f1^2*f2*h*m1*mp + 4*R*a1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1^2*fp2*h*m1^2*mp - 8*R*a1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*h*m1^2*mp + 4*R*a1*e1^2*ep2^2*f1*f2*h*m1*mp*r*t1 - 4*R*a1*e1^2*ep2*f*f1*f2*fp2*h*m1*t1 + 8*R*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1^2*f2*h*m1*mp*r - 8*R*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1*f2^2*h*m1*mp*r - 2*R*a1*e1*ep1*ep2*f*f1^2*f2*fp2*h*m1 - 2*R*a1*e1*ep2^2*f*f1*f2^2*h*r*t1 + 2*R*e1^2*ep1^2*f1^2*fp2^2*h*m1^2 - 4*R*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*h*m1*r*t1 +\\\r\n 2*R*e1^2*ep2^2*f2^2*h*r^2*t1^2 + a1^2*e1^2*ep2^2*f1^2*h^2*m1^2*mp^2 + 2*a1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1^2*fp2*h^2*m1^2*mp - 4*a1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*h^2*m1^2*mp + 2*a1*e1^2*ep2^2*f1*f2*h^2*m1*mp*r*t1 + 4*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1^2*f2*h^2*m1*mp*r - 4*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1*f2^2*h^2*m1*mp*r + e1^2*ep1^2*f1^2*fp2^2*h^2*m1^2 - 2*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*h^2*m1*r*t1 + e1^2*ep2^2*f2^2*h^2*r^2*t1^2)^(1/2) - ep1*f1*mp*(R^2*a1^2*e1^2*ep2^2*f1^2*m1^2*mp^2 + 2*R^2*a1^2*e1*ep2^2*f*f1^2*f2*m1*mp + R^2*a1^2*ep2^2*f^2*f1^2*f2^2 + 2*R^2*a1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1^2*fp2*m1^2*mp - 4*R^2*a1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*m1^2*mp + 2*R^2*a1*e1^2*ep2^2*f1*f2*m1*mp*r*t1 - 4*R^2*a1*e1^2*ep2*f*f1*f2*fp2*m1*t1 + 4*R^2*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1^2*f2*m1*mp*r - 4*R^2*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1*f2^2*m1*mp*r - 2*R^2*a1*e1*ep1*ep2*f*f1^2*f2*fp2*m1 - 2*R^2*a1*e1*ep2^2*f*f1*f2^2*r*t1 + R^2*e1^2*ep1^2*f1^2*fp2^2*m1^2 - 2*R^2*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*m1*r*t1 + R^2*e1^2*ep2^2*f2^2*r^2*t1^2 + 2*R*a1^2*e1^2*ep2^2*f1^2*h*m1^2*mp^2 + 2*R*a1^2*e1*ep2^2*f*f1^2*f2*h*m1*mp + 4*R*a\\\r\n1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1^2*fp2*h*m1^2*mp - 8*R*a1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*h*m1^2*mp + 4*R*a1*e1^2*ep2^2*f1*f2*h*m1*mp*r*t1 - 4*R*a1*e1^2*ep2*f*f1*f2*fp2*h*m1*t1 + 8*R*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1^2*f2*h*m1*mp*r - 8*R*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1*f2^2*h*m1*mp*r - 2*R*a1*e1*ep1*ep2*f*f1^2*f2*fp2*h*m1 - 2*R*a1*e1*ep2^2*f*f1*f2^2*h*r*t1 + 2*R*e1^2*ep1^2*f1^2*fp2^2*h*m1^2 - 4*R*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*h*m1*r*t1 + 2*R*e1^2*ep2^2*f2^2*h*r^2*t1^2 + a1^2*e1^2*ep2^2*f1^2*h^2*m1^2*mp^2 + 2*a1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1^2*fp2*h^2*m1^2*mp - 4*a1*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*h^2*m1^2*mp + 2*a1*e1^2*ep2^2*f1*f2*h^2*m1*mp*r*t1 + 4*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1^2*f2*h^2*m1*mp*r - 4*a1*e1*ep1*ep2^2*f1*f2^2*h^2*m1*mp*r + e1^2*ep1^2*f1^2*fp2^2*h^2*m1^2 - 2*e1^2*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*fp2*h^2*m1*r*t1 + e1^2*ep2^2*f2^2*h^2*r^2*t1^2)^(1/2) - R*e1*ep1^2*f1^2*fp2*m1*mp - e1*ep1^2*f1^2*fp2*h*m1*mp + e1*ep1*ep2*f2^2*h*mp*r*t1 - R*a1*e1*ep1*ep2*f1^2*m1*mp^2 - a1*e1*ep1*ep2*f1^2*h*m1*mp^2 + 2*R*e1*ep1*f*f1*f2*fp2*t1 + R*a1*ep1*ep2*f*f1*f2^2*mp - R*a1*ep1*ep2*f*f1^2*f2*mp + R*e1\\\r\n*ep1^2*f1*f2*fp2*m1*mp + R*e1*ep1*ep2*f2^2*mp*r*t1 + e1*ep1^2*f1*f2*fp2*h*m1*mp - R*e1*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*mp*r*t1 - e1*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*h*mp*r*t1 + R*a1*e1*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*m1*mp^2 + a1*e1*ep1*ep2*f1*f2*h*m1*mp^2)/(2*e1*ep2*f2*(R*f*f2*t1 - R*ep1*f1*m1*mp + R*ep1*f2*m1*mp - ep1*f1*h*m1*mp + ep1*f2*h*m1*mp))
```

Comment: This is not solving it numerically. What is the problem with this solution?

Comment: Like I pointed out, it gives me too many if conditions ahead. So it says, if R + h =0; then this solution is valid, if something else is 0 then this solution is valid.

Comment: Okay so what is the problem with that?

Comment: “Matlab to solve with an analytical solution (not numerically, I can do this in Mathematica)” — You’ve got this backwards. Traditionally, MATLAB is for numerical solutions, and Mathematica for analytical solutions. You can do both on both systems nowadays, but that is where they started out, and where their strengths still are.

Comment: The conditions are part of the mathematics of the equation you put in, not part of MATLAB! you can not change maths to get a better answer! Maths is maths. It basically is telling you: the solution works as long as you dont get undefined solutions, such as `0/0`. Simply that. You can ignore them if you want, just know there are particular cases where the answer is not valid

Comment: @CrisLuengo I tried to solve this equation in Mathematica..but it seems to take an awfully long time and then aborts. I was guessing that it is expensive for it to calculate it. So, I wanted to try solving on MATLAB to see if I get an easier solution. It appears that it is spitting out 1? root (see the edits). I know that there are atleast 3 - 4 roots to this solution.

Comment: @Biotechgeek Your equation is of the form `a/b=0`. Thus, you can solve the equation `a=0` with the condition that `b≠0`. Using Mathematica, I get 4 solutions for `a=0`, and 3 conditions (2 are the same) for `b=0`. The conditions are very important to ensure that you do not get a division by zero.

Comment: You may be able to use the ‘simplify’ command in Matlab, but this will only help if there are terms that can actually be eliminated.